# How to I fix invalid firebase api key?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

In a react firebase project  I am getting the error = " firebase: error (auth/api-key-not-valid.-please-pass-a-valid-api-key.)" Why am I getting this error?

Here is my firebase initializing code:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey:process.env.REACT_APP_authDomain,
  authDomain:process.env.REACT_APP_apiKey,
  projectId:process.env.REACT_APP_projectId,
  storageBucket:process.env.REACT_APP_storageBucket,
  messagingSenderId:process.env.REACT_APP_messagingSenderId,
  appId:process.env.REACT_APP_appId
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const auth = getAuth(app);


export default auth;
```

Comment: We can't see any of the values that you're passing to Firebase.  Have you tried deubgging this by logging the values and see if they are what you expect?

Comment: In the Firebase console project settings it provides all the correct initialization code. And your code appears to be correct.  However, since the api key is a variable in your code it's possible that it has the wrong value when you use it.  And that could be easily checked via the debugger.

Comment: Try apiKey: `${process.env.REACT_APP_authDomain}` ... notice ${} format

Answer (score 0):

1. In the .env file where you put all the firebase given api keys put those keys in a formate like below. No extra punctuation.

   REACT_APP_authDomain = YOUR_FIREBASE_KEY
2. Check all the api keys are OK
3. If all things are OK. Stop your 'react hotreload' and start your react app again by 'npm start'

At last I am seeing that you are providing wrong value for keys. You have provided 'apikey' the 'REACT_APP_authDomain' value and authDomain the 'REACT_APP_apiKey' value. Check that also. Good luck .

```
apiKey:process.env.REACT_APP_authDomain,
authDomain:process.env.REACT_APP_apiKey
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do it like this:

```
apiKey: String(process.env.REACT_APP_apiKey),
authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_authDomain,
projectId: String(process.env.REACT_APP_projectId),
storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_storageBucket,
messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_messagingSenderId,
appId: String(process.env.REACT_APP_appId),
measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_measurementId
```

Comment: What did you change? What were the issue? Can you [edit] your post and add more details?